# Javascript Tooltip doesn't work on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

Tooltip based on drop down which working in all browsers except Chrome

```js
function showTip(oSel) {
  var theTip = document.getElementById("spnTip");
  theTip.style.top = window.event.clientY + 20;
  theTip.style.left = window.event.clientX;
  theTip.innerText = oSel.options[oSel.selectedIndex].text;
  theTip.style.visibility = "visible";
}

function hideTip() {
  document.getElementById("spnTip").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

```html
<select onmouseout="hideTip()" onmouseover="showTip(this)" style="width:100px;">
  <option>Have you seen the latest M. Night Shyamalan film?</option>
  <option>It's called The Village.</option>
  <option>Although the critics didn't like it, I think it was extremely well done.</option>
  <option>You will be kept in suspense even if you think you have figured out the ending.</option>
</select>
<span onmouseout="hideTip()" style="position:absolute; top:-35px visibility:hidden; background:#fefed5;
 border:1px solid #666666; padding:2px; font-size:12pt; font-family:Tahoma;" id="spnTip"></span>
```

Comment: Ah, quite right.  Fixed that.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Do you get any errors? Does it appear in the wrong place? Crash your computer?

Comment: it if working fine :)
 ,unfortunately it doesn't work on Firefox :(

Comment: Could you please don't degrade me.
I'm just student of web development. 
just let me know what wrong I done then I can study on it.

So please don't degrade pls pls

Comment: @ShafeerAthimannil I am assuming the downvote was because you did not provide any error messages you get in FireFox. install FireBug, or press CTRL+SHIFT+J and open up the error console.

Comment: @rlemon It is working on FF,IE and Safari only problem with Chrome ehich I already mentioned on the title.

please don't degrade me. Just let me know the wrongs i'm happy to improve

Comment: no one is degrading you, we are trying to help. stop being so defensive. like you mentioned you are a student. We are trying to teach you things that will ultimately make you a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of errors in your code.. I will address a few.

innerText does not work in Firefox. you need to use textContent. 
Also, window.event does not return anything in firefox. You need to attach to the event object returned by the function invocation. (did i get that right?)

Here is an example of binding the event to a function, and making use of the event object and *this*. 
because we are attaching the function to an event called on the select element, *this* will point to that element. Therefore we do not need to pass it to the function.

```
var showTip = function(event) {
    var theTip = document.getElementById("spnTip");
    theTip.style.top = event.clientY + 20 + "px";
    theTip.style.left = event.clientX + "px";
    theTip.innerText = theTip.textContent = this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText || this.options[this.selectedIndex].textContent;
    theTip.style.display = "block";
    theTip.addEventListener("mouseout", hideTip, false);
};
var hideTip = function() {
    this.style.display = "none";
};


var sel = document.getElementById("selectId");
sel.addEventListener("mouseover", showTip, false);
```

You will need to add complaint code for IE as well.

```
<select id="selectId" style="width:100px;">
<option>Have you seen the latest M. Night Shyamalan film?</option>
<option>It's called The Village.</option>
<option>Although the critics didn't like it, I think it was extremely well done.</option>
<option>You will be kept in suspense even if you think you have figured out the ending.</option>
</select>
<span style="position:absolute; top:-35px; display: none; background:#fefed5;
 border:1px solid #666666; padding:2px; font-size:12pt; font-family:Tahoma;" id="spnTip"></span>
```

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/CRUgv/4/)